# Groovy: What happens if the safe navigation operator returns null on a primitive assignment?

Tags: groovy, null, int, variable-assignment, primitive

```
Character parrot = null
int hp = parrot?.hp
if (hp < 0) {
    print (parrot+" is pining for the fjords.")
}
```

Essentially, what happens in the second line? Is `hp` set to `null`, even though it's a primitive? Do we get an exception? Or is it, for some reason, set to `0`?

(Research indicates that `(null < 0) == true`, so that part is fine.)

Also, do things change if we instead write:

```
Character parrot = null
if (parrot?.hp < 0) {
    print (parrot+" is pining for the fjords.")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Or is this a rhetorical question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you get:

   ```
   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException:
        Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'.
        Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead
   ```
2. Yes.  As you say, `null < 0` so you get the output:

   ```
   null is pining for the fjords
   ```